# Calculation of $E\left[\frac{X}{E[X]}\right]$

Tags: expected-value

how can I rewrite $E\left[\frac{X}{E[X]}\right]$?

I did:
$E\left[\frac{X}{E[X]}\right] = E[X] * E\left[\frac{1}{E[X]}\right] + \operatorname{cov}\left(X, \frac{1}{E[X]}\right)$

How can I continue?

Is $E\left[\frac{1}{E[X]}\right] = \frac{1}{E[X]}$ ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

$\frac{1}{\mathbf{E}[X]}$ is just a constant, so by linearity of expectation you have

$$
\mathbf{E}[\frac{X}{\mathbf{E}[X]}] = \frac{1}{\mathbf{E}[X]} \mathbf{E}[X] = 1
$$

Comment: sure! Thanks a lot!